# Why my geth fast node suddenly stopped running?

Tags: go-ethereum, ropsten, geth-debugging, fast-sync, leveldb

Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: gap (#3) in the chain between ancients and leveldb

when I run geth node for ropsten by :

```
geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --cache=512 --rpc --ws --shh console
```

It throws Error:

```
INFO [09-11|21:33:55.437] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [09-11|21:33:55.437] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
ERROR[09-11|21:33:55.438] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[09-11|21:33:55.438] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[09-11|21:33:55.438] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=1 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[09-11|21:33:55.438] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=ledger vendor=11415 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[09-11|21:33:55.438] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=21324 failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
ERROR[09-11|21:33:55.438] Failed to enumerate USB devices          hub=trezor vendor=4617  failcount=2 err="failed to initialize libusb: libusb: unknown error [code -99]"
INFO [09-11|21:33:55.440] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.9.3-stable-cfbb969d/linux-amd64/go1.11.5
INFO [09-11|21:33:55.440] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=128.00MiB dirty=128.00MiB
INFO [09-11|21:33:55.440] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata cache=256.00MiB handles=524288
INFO [09-11|21:33:55.641] Opened ancient database                  database=/root/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata/ancient
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: gap (#3) in the chain between ancients and leveldb
```

I tried to delete ancient directory from chaindata but got this:

```
 Error starting protocol stack: ancient chain segments already extracted, please set --datadir.ancient to the correct path
```

Comment: Can you launch geth with higher verbosity? It appear the database got corrupted, perhaps an unclean shutdown.

Comment: Yeah. Database got corrupted. Didnt't Find any way to fix it.  I just resynced whole node and It took me about 20hrs.

Comment: I am having the same error please see the debug log with the highest verbosity: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/e935f5e488e675b2283e6ac36fd4832b

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20383

> Geth persists data after 1 hour worth of block processing (so for
> example if your blocks are processed in 100ms, that's 10/s * 60s * 60m
> = after 36000 blocks). If your network is super light (i.e. mostly empty blocks), it may happen that it takes a very very long time until
> blocks are flushed.
>
> An ungraceful shutdown should still eventually sync up with the
> network when connections are made to old nodes that are still healthy,
> so it should eventually self heal itself.
>
> Currently there is no way to configure the period for these
> persistency rounds because every piece of data pushed to disk cannot
> be garbage collected any more, so the more frequent, the more junk.
> You can hack around the issue currently with your workaround of
> restarting Geth periodically.
>
> We have an alternative idea in the works that would persist the
> in-memory state not to the database, rather to a flat file. That will
> allow users to configure wall-clock timeouts for the backups without
> adding junk to their databases. Not sure when that will ship however,
> it's not a high priority feature.